# Is python set s.difference_update(t) O(m X n)

Tags: python, set, time-complexity

**Problem statement:**

I am working on a problem where I have a database with a huge list of files from filesystem.
If a bunch of files are deleted from the system, the same should be updated in database.

**Approach:**

Query list of files from db and list of files from filesystem.
Then compare if each of the files from db is in the other list.
Delete if not found
To avoid a lookup of each file from the list repeatedly, I am planning to use sets in python and the difference_update() method

**Question:**

Internally, will this again have the complexity of O(m X n), like the other approach of repeated searching or is it optimized to reduce the complexity ?

Comment: Because the lookup in a set is `O(1)`, rather than the `O(n)` of a list, the overall complexity will be `O(m)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's going to be `O(len(t))` as stated in the comment, because of the set constant look up time.
Also confirmed in http://python-reference.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/sets/difference_update.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.

BTW, is there any other more optimized, pythonic way to achieve this ??